# How to convert GeoJSON with mixed and NULL geometries to SQLite?

Tags: qgis, geojson, ogr2ogr, spatialite, sqlite

I am trying to convert a GeoJSON file into SpatiaLite, so I can load it as a SpatiaLite layer into QGIS, as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32533/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-layer-in-qgis-while-there-is-an-active-query).

Converting the file in QGIS with "save as.." did not work (see also [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80927/qgis-export-esri-shapefile-to-spatialite-format-issue)), which is why I tried ogr2ogr in the command line to do the trick. After a few attempts I managed to convert it as follows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr -f sqlite -dsco spatialite=yes mydata.sqlite mydata.geojson -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI
```

This works fine for an input file with mixed geometries but does not seem to work with my file, which also contains NULL geometries. In this case, I end up with a .sqlite file that I can open in QGIS as a vector layer, but not as a SpatiaLite layer. Here it only loads the attribute table and no geometries, which are listed as "Unknown Geometries".

Does anyone have an idea how I could resolve this?

[image: "Unknown Geometry"]

Comment: Do you need also those features which are without geometry?

Comment: OpenJUMP can handle quite well all kind of geometries, even empty ones, on the same layer. It has also a brand new GeoJSON driver which might be worth trying. Release version does not have the driver, take a nightly build from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files./OpenJUMP_snapshots/